# Can't save the data in shelve module Python

Tags: python

I want to create a python file that when user inputs a value, it will save to a dictionary and update the binary file created by shelve module.
The problem is that when I run the python file again, the dictionary is not updated.
There is no error code or anything and I don't know what to do.

```
import shelve
menubook = shelve.open('menu_data', writeback=True)

menubookA = {'main':'toast', 'sub':'egg', 'drink':'milk'}

print(menubookA)
print(menubookA['drink']) 

key = input("Enter key: ")
value = input("Enter value: ")

menubookA[key] = value
print(menubookA) # When I check the dictionary here, it has been updated but when I run the program again, the value and key added are gone. 

menubook.close()
```

I would appreciate if anyone could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You obviously forgot to write the data back to the file:

```
import shelve

menubook = shelve.open("menu_data", writeback=True)

# Read data from the file
for key, value in menubook.items():
    print("Key: %s = %s" % (key, value))

menubookA = {"main": "toast", "sub": "egg", "drink": "milk"}

print(menubookA)
print(menubookA["drink"])

key = input("Enter key: ")
value = input("Enter value: ")

menubookA[key] = value
print(menubookA)  # When I check the dictionary here, it has been updated but when I run the program again, the value and key added are gone.

# Write data back to the file
menubook.update(menubookA)

menubook.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. When I tried the code you had shared with, it didn't work the way I wanted either. If the dictionary was updated, when I run the program again ,the first print(menubookA) has the key and value I had added, right? But the dictionary was still the same as before. Could you help me?

Comment: As the script above, you will always create new variable `menubookA` everytime you run the file.
I think to fit your need, you can edit `menubookA = {"main": "toast", ...}` into `menubookA = dict(menubook.items())`